# How to determine series expansion for $x^2 \left[ K_{i\alpha+1}(x) K_{i\alpha-1}(x) - K_{i\alpha}(x)^2 \right] $ for small $x>0$?

Tags: taylor-expansion, bessel-functions

Supposing that $\alpha>0$ and $x>0$, define the function:
$$
f(x,\alpha) = x^2 \left[ K_{i\alpha+1}(x) K_{i\alpha-1}(x) - K_{i\alpha}(x)^2 \right] 
$$
where $K_{i \alpha}(x)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind of order $i \alpha$ and evaluated at the point $x$.

I am interested in a series expansion fo $f(x,\alpha)$ near $x=0$. I am thrown off because [DLMF is unavailable due to the government shutdown](https://dlmf.nist.gov/) (this is my usual go-to for facts about special functions). I am not able to find a series expansion for $K_{i \alpha}(x)$ near $x=0$ for an order $i \alpha$ being complex-valued. Is there a way of determining the above?

**EDIT:** Maybe I am misinterpreting [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function). I quote a series expansion for $0 < |z| \ll \sqrt{1+b}$ where
$$
K_{b}(z) \approx \frac{\Gamma(z)}{2} \left( \frac{2}{z} \right)^{b}
$$
I thought it looks like this is only true for real $b$. Is this true for complex valued $b = i \alpha$? If this is true then I find I have
$$
f(x,\alpha) \approx x^2 \frac{\Gamma(i\alpha + 1)\Gamma(i\alpha - 1)}{4} \left( \frac{2}{x} \right)^{i \alpha + 1}\left( \frac{2}{x} \right)^{i \alpha - 1} - x^2 \frac{\Gamma(i\alpha)^2}{4} \left( \frac{2}{x} \right)^{i\alpha } \left( \frac{2}{x} \right)^{i\alpha }
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct expansion for $z\to 0$ is (see [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/03.04.06.0029.01))
 \begin{equation}
  K_\nu(z)=\frac{1}{2}\Gamma(\nu)\left( \frac{z}{2} \right)^{-\nu}\left( 1+O(z^2) \right)+\frac{1}{2}\Gamma(-\nu)\left( \frac{z}{2} \right)^{\nu}\left( 1+O(z^2) \right)
  \end{equation} 
  for $\nu\notin\mathbb{Z}$. By keeping the leading term only,
  \begin{align}
    x^2 \left[ K_{i\alpha+1}(x) K_{i\alpha-1}(x) - K_{i\alpha}(x)^2 \right]&=\frac{x^2}{4}\left[\Gamma(1+i\alpha)\left( \frac{x}{2} \right)^{-i\alpha-1} \Gamma(1-i\alpha)\left( \frac{x}{2} \right)^{i\alpha-1}+O(1)\right]\\
    &=\frac{\pi \alpha}{\sinh\pi\alpha}+O(x^2)
  \end{align}